# Best practice for static references in libgdx project?

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d, game-development

My libGDX / box2d project is targeting Android, iOS and Desktop as a platform. I have read somewhere that it is not good to use a static Texture Atlas, because it might be removed from the memory, once the app is in background. Therefore I am passing the same Texture Atlas as parameter to my controller classes, but I still have many static variables (constants) for all kinds of purposes. I use them for paths, regions, box2d, music, user data, ... Isn't there a probability that these variables will be removed too, when the app is in background? Should I change that? How would I approach that?

```
public static final String ATLAS_PATH = "atlas/myAtlas.atlas";
public static final String ATLAS_REGION_OFF = "off";
public static final String SFX_KEY_AIRHORN = "airhorn";
public static final short BIT_GROUND = 0x0001;
public static final String USER_DATA_HEAD = "head";
public static final short ID_AND_RENDER_ORDER_PLAYER = 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to avoid constants. `static final` Strings and primitives are considered constants and take up a trivial amount of memory.

For other types of objects, it might make sense to use `static final` if it's some kind of object that you want to always be in memory, even if the game is closed and reopened. This should not be used for large objects. On Android, when you close the Activity hosting the game, anything that is referenced statically stays in memory until the game is reopened or Android completely destroys the app to recover memory.

Using `static` without `final` can lead to messy, difficult-to-test code, and makes it very easy to leak objects. There are certain cases where it might be the best option, though.